# Heat equation satisfied by $u(\lambda x,\lambda^2 t)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans p45

We are given the homogeneous heat equation for $u:\bar{U} \times [0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$, where $U\subset \Bbb R^n$ is open.

$$u_t-\Delta u =0.$$

He writes that if $u$ satisfies this, then so does $u(\lambda x, \lambda^2 t)$.

I tried to verify this:
$$u(\lambda x,\lambda^2 t)=u(\lambda x_1,\dots,\lambda x_n,\lambda^2 t)=u(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_{n+1}).$$

Then $$\frac{\partial u(\lambda x,\lambda^2 t)}{\partial t}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_i}\frac{\partial \xi_i}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_{n+1}}\frac{\partial \xi_{n+1}}{\partial t}=\lambda^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_{n+1}}$$

And
$$\Delta u=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_j}\frac{\partial \xi_j}{\partial x_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\left(\lambda u_{\xi_i}\right)=\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial u_{\xi_i}}{\partial \xi_i}\frac{\partial \xi_i}{\partial x_i}$$
$$=\lambda^2 \sum_{i=1}^n u_{\xi_i\xi_i}$$

So we have:
$$u_t(\lambda x,\lambda^2 t)-\Delta u(\lambda x,\lambda^2 t)=\lambda^2\left(u_{\xi_{n+1}}-\sum_{i=1}^n u_{\xi_i\xi_i}\right)$$

I feel I am meant to conclude that this vanishes, since the bracketed term satisfies the heat equation if I relabel, but how do I say this properly?

Comment: You simply say it as you did: the term in the brackets is zero as $u$ satisfy the heat equation (what symbols we use to denote the variables play no difference). There is not much more you need to say here.